# how to solve concatenate issue with.cell()? row = row work, column = column gives error

Tags: python-2.7, openpyxl

I am looping through an excel sheet, looking for a specific name. When found, I print the position of the cell and the value.

I would like to find the position and value of a neighbouring cell, however I can't get .cell() to work by adding 2, indicating I would like the cell 2 columns away in the same row.

row= row works, but column= column gives error, and column + 2 gives error. Maybe this is due to me listing columns as 'ABCDEFGHIJ' earlier in my code? (For full code, see below)

```
print 'Cell position {} has value {}'.format(cell_name, currentSheet[cell_name].value)
print 'Cell position next door TEST {}'.format(currentSheet.cell(row=row, column=column +2))
```

Full code:

```
file = openpyxl.load_workbook('test6.xlsx', read_only = True)
allSheetNames = file.sheetnames

#print("All sheet names {}" .format(file.sheetnames))

for sheet in allSheetNames:
    print('Current sheet name is {}'.format(sheet))
    currentSheet = file[sheet]

    for row in range(1, currentSheet.max_row + 1):
        #print row
        for column in 'ABCDEFGHIJ':  
            cell_name = '{}{}'.format(column,row)
        
            if currentSheet[cell_name].value == 'sign_name': 
                print 'Cell position {} has value {}'.format(cell_name, currentSheet[cell_name].value)
                print 'Cell position TEST {}'.format(currentSheet.cell(row=row, column=column +2))
```

I get this output:

```
Current sheet name is Sheet1
Current sheet name is Sheet2
Cell position D5 has value sign_name
```

and:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

I get the same error if I try "column = column" as "column = column +2".

Why does row=row work, but column=column dosen't? And how to find the cell name of the cell to the right of my resulting D5 cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The reason `row=row` works and `column=column` doesn't is because *your* `column` value is a string (letter from A to J) while the `column` *argument* of a cell is expecting an `int` (A would be 1, B would be 2, Z would be 26, etc.)
2. There are a few changes I would make in order to more effectively iterate through the cells and find a neighbor. Firstly, OpenPyXl offers `sheet.iter_rows()`, which given no arguments, will provide a generator of all rows that are used in the sheet. So you can iterate with

`for row in currentSheet.iter_rows():`

`for cell in row:`

because each `row` is a generator of cells in that row.

Then in this new nested for loop, you can get the current column index with `cell.column` (D would give 4) and the cell to the right (increment by one column) would be `currentSheet.cell(row=row, column=cell.column+1)`

Note the difference between the two `cell`'s: `currentSheet.cell()` is a request for a specific cell while `cell.column+1` is the column index of the *current* cell incremented by 1.

Relevant OpenPyXl documentation:

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html

Comment: Or, even simpler: `for row in currentSheet…`